# When to use a class component and when to use a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to react.When I go for an interview they ask me When to use a class component and when to use a functional component ?.I do not know the answer to this question.I know the difference between the two.How best to answer this question?

Answer (score 3):

In current post-hooks era the answer is simple: you always use function components.

Answer (score 1):

Simply explain the difference.  You said you know what the difference is, so tell them what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use class components when you need to keep component-level state or use lifecycle components. Functional components can now use state and some lifecycle methods with [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html) though, so it's up to personal preference.

Functional components are considered easier to read and are less code than classes. They should be used in [presentational](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) components (small components dealing with how things look, not how things work).